# How can i make that the function in c++ will be like a property in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have this function in C++:

```
List<String^> ^GetCodecs()
    {
        List<String^> ^l = gcnew List<String^>;

        String ^s;

        for (int i=0;i<3333;i++)
        {
        s = gcnew String(Encoder_GetCodecName( i ));
        l->Add(s);
        }

        return l;
    }
```

And this is in C# i'm getting the List:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>(f.GetCodecs());
```

So l contain 3333 indexs some filled with codec's names.

What i want to do now is that in C# instead doing: List l = new List(f.GetCodecs());

To make somehow that i will be able to do for example:

f.GetCodecs.

When i will click the point after the GetCodecs it will open a new big list of codecs that i will be able to move with the arrows down and up and then select the one i want.

Like a property or something like that. And not like a List it is now.

EDIT !

Example:

I'm doing f.getcodecs.

After the last point i will see the codecs like this visualy:

mpej
xvid
divx

I will see them at once without the need to loop over it.

Comment: Yeah me too. This is not a property is C#, is it?

Comment: tnw now in C# i'm doing List<string> l = new List....all this as above. Then l contain a List of codec's . I want to make somehow that instead doing List<string> l = new.....Just to make f.GetCodecs. after the . the point the last point it will show me a List so i can move between the codec's up and down. Visualy its like       a ListView instead looping c# through the List and find the codec i want to make that if i'm doing f.GetCodecs. it iwll show me the List.

Comment: Pacane yes but now to look over the codecs or select them i need to loop over the List in C#. And i want to make that i will do something like. f.getcodes.    after the last point i will see automatic a list of all the codecs

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think you're asking:

> When I type `f.GetCodecs.` **in the C++ editor**, I want **the IDE** to
>   display a list of codecs after that, so that I can select an item from
>   a list, rather than having to type `f.GetCodecs.mpegCodec`.

If that's what you want, then you'd need GetCodecs to be (or to return, if it's a method) an object with fields/methods with the names you want. You'd have to pick the names that would appear when you design the object, it wouldn't be based on the codecs installed on the machine, for example.

Comment: Probably he needs some code generation to create those members based on the set of codecs which exist.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correctly, there is a good article on CodeProject that shows you how to do this: [C++/CLI Properties - Syntactic sugar for accessor methods](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10352/C-CLI-Properties-Syntactic-sugar-for-accessor-meth).

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly make it a property:

```
property List<String^> ^GetCodecs
{
    List<String^>^ get()
    {
        List<String^> ^l = gcnew List<String^>;
        String ^s;

        for (int i=0;i<3333;i++)
        {
            s = gcnew String(Encoder_GetCodecName( i ));
            l->Add(s);
        }

        return l;
    }
}
```

I don't have a compiler ready so I couldn't test this code, but you get the idea. More details can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10352/C-CLI-Properties-Syntactic-sugar-for-accessor-meth).